# Shinkai had to stop working on Your Name (Kimi no Na wa), what was left incomplete or unbalanced?

Tags: production, your-name

According to the [Wikipedia article on Makoto Shinkai's *Your Name*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Your_Name#Critical_response):

> Despite the praise he received, Makoto Shinkai insisted that the film
>   is not as good as it could have been: "There are things we could not
>   do, Masashi Ando [Director of animation] wanted to keep working [on]
>   but had to stop us for lack of money ... For me it’s incomplete,
>   unbalanced. The plot is fine but the film is not at all perfect. Two
>   years was not enough.

Does anyone know how Shinkai planned to complete and balance the film?

Answer (score 2):

Backing up Shinkai's statement that the "plot is fine," there are no major differences between the film and its novelization, also written by Shinkai. (source: the afterword to the novel itself, 新海誠 『小説 君の名は。』 角川書店〈角川文庫〉p.255, as quoted on Japanese Wikipedia)

In another Japanese-language interview, he said that [he felt the film was completed with no issues](https://www.cinematoday.jp/news/N0087651) (無事).

I searched around but could not find the full text of this interview, nor other interviews where he made statements like this. I think that in this interview he must have been referring to aspects of the animation which embarrassed him, and that the interviewer hyped this up. It would certainly be impolite for him to emphasize this embarrassment in multiple interviews, as unlike Miyazaki, Shinkai was not his own animation director, so he would implicitly be blaming Ando as well as himself.